# Mesh Thread network using Sub-1GHz

Tags: thread, sx1276

I want to implement a Mesh Thread network on Sub-1GHz especially on 868MHz using the Semtech's SX1276 as a radio chip.
I bough two modules to do some tests.

I'm trying to find out how these kind of networks are formed.

I mean, how are they really formed at the beginning. 
What happens when all of them are powered at the same time? Which does decide to be the router, which does the node? which does the parent and which does the child?

Is this frequency suitable for that kind of networks? I want to spread over many nodes in an agriculture and/or industrial area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used but yes it is suitable to avoid collisions when using RSSI to listen before talk.

https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/do-lora-wan-nodes-perform-any-activity-detection-and-or-collision-detection/1353

Comment: *Although some leader in USA may not  follow these rules and love to tweet chaos of verbal collisions or shoot and run transmissions<lol>*